# Program returns incorrect answer and "-nan(ind)". What did I do wrong?

Tags: c, quadratic

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void main()
{
float a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
float disc = b*b - 4 * a*c;
float sing = -b / (2 * a);
float lin = -c / b;
float quad1 = (-b + (disc)) / (2 * a);
float quad2 = (-b - (disc)) / (2 * a);
printf_s("Please enter the coefficients a, b, and c\n");
scanf_s("%g %g %g", &a, &b, &c);
if (a == 0)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        if (c == 0)
        {
            printf_s("There are infinite solutions\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf_s("There is no solution\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf_s("The singular solution is %g\n", lin);
    }
}
else
{
    if (disc < 0)
    {
        printf_s("There is no real solution\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        if (disc == 0)
        {
            printf_s("The singular solution is %g\n", sing);
        }
        else
        {
            printf_s("The solutions are x1 = %g and x2 = %g\n", quad1, quad2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to build a quadratic formula calculator. When I plug in a = 2, b = 1, and c = -21, I expect to receive x = 3 and x = -3.5
But instead I get the output "The singular solution is -nan(ind)"
What does this mean? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calculating the value of `disc` *before* input. Change the order.

That also goes for `sing`, `lin`, `quad1` and `quad2`.

```
float a, b, c;
printf_s("Please enter the coefficients a, b, and c\n");
scanf_s("%g %g %g", &a, &b, &c);
float disc = b*b - 4 * a*c;
float sing = -b / (2 * a);
float lin = -c / b;
float quad1 = (-b + (disc)) / (2 * a);
float quad2 = (-b - (disc)) / (2 * a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not initialized or recalculated retroactively.

For example, with

```
float disc = b*b - 4 * a*c;
```

the initialization is equal to `0 * 0 - 4 * 0 * 0`, i.e. `0`.

Define the variables, then read input, and *then* do the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

See these lines

```
 float sing = -b / (2 * a);
 float lin = -c / b;
```

here, you're attempting a divide-by-zero, which does not make sense.

You probably need to move the operations after you have read the values from user.